# How to read a textbox from a thread other than the one it was created on?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am fairly new to C# and I have written several functioning programs, but all of them have been single thread applications. This is my first multi-threaded application and I am struggling to resolve this "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cbLogType' accessed from a thread other than the one it was created on" error. My application searches Windows Event viewer for a user defined Event ID in a user defined Event Log Source(cbLogType). I am using a backgroundworker process to do all the work and I am using the worker.reportprogress to update a label, however, I receive the above error when debugging. I have tried several Invoke methods, but none seem to resolve my error. I have also tried removing the combobox and  setting the Log Source directly in the code, which works to an extent, but still fails. I have included my code and any help would be greatly appreciated. I suspect that I might not be using the Invoke method correctly. Thanks in advance!
CODE:

```
    private void bgWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Events.log"))
                MessageBox.Show("File 'Events.log' already exists. All new data will be appended to the log file!", "Warning!");

            string message = string.Empty;
            string eventID = (tbEventID.Text);

            string text;

            EventLog eLog = new EventLog();
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { text = cbLogType.Text; });
            eLog.Source = (this.cbLogType.Text); // I am receiving the error here
            eLog.MachineName = ".";

            int EventID = 0;
            string strValue = string.Empty;
            strValue = tbEventID.Text.Trim();
            //string message = string.Empty;

            EventID = Convert.ToInt32(strValue); // Convert string to integer

            foreach (EventLogEntry entry in eLog.Entries)
            {
                int entryCount = 1;
                if (cbDateFilter.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (entry.TimeWritten > dtPicker1.Value && entry.TimeWritten < dtPicker2.Value)
                        if (entry.InstanceId == EventID)
                            message = "Event entry matching " + (tbEventID.Text) + " was found in " + (cbLogType.Text);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Events.log", true))
                        writer.WriteLine("EventID: " + entry.InstanceId +
                            "\r\nDate Created: " + entry.TimeWritten +
                            "\r\nEntry Type: " + entry.EntryType +
                            "\r\nMachinename: " + entry.MachineName +
                            "\r\n" +
                            "\r\nMessage: " + entry.Message +
                            "\r\n");
                    if (entry.InstanceId != EventID)
                        message = "No event ids matching " + (tbEventID.Text) + " was found in " + (cbLogType.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cbDateFilter.Checked == false)
                    {
                        if (entry.InstanceId == EventID)
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Events.log", true))
                                writer.WriteLine("EventID: " + entry.InstanceId +
                                    "\r\nDate Created: " + entry.TimeWritten +
                                    "\r\nEntry Type: " + entry.EntryType +
                                    "\r\nMachinename: " + entry.MachineName +
                                    "\r\n" +
                                    "\r\nMessage: " + entry.Message +
                                    "\r\n");
                        else if (entry.InstanceId != EventID)
                            message = "No event ids matching " + (tbEventID.Text) + " was found in " + (cbLogType.Text);
                    }
                    bgWorker1.ReportProgress((entryCount) * 10, message);
                    entryCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void bgWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblStat.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing cbLogType in a non-UI thread.

Change to

```
eLog.Source = text;
```

Comment: When I change to eLog.Source = text; I get a new error: Use of unassigned local variable 'text'. Isn't text assigned in the invoke method?

Comment: The compiler cannot statically determine it was assigned, so it complains. Just declare it as string text = string.Empty;